# Android get number of file from url folder

Tags: android

I'm trying to get how many image are in my host folder.
I have ftp access and ssl certificate access.

This is the php file and work fine

```
$dir = getcwd(); 


$i = 0; 

if( $handle = opendir($dir) ) { 

    while( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) { 
        if( !in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
            $i++; 
    } 
} 




echo "$i "; 


?>
```

i would like to receive the result on android like
intent

Any code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the ideal way to do it, at all. I had a similar requirement for my app [Snap Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cybersky.snapsearch) - this is how I did it:

**Step 1)** Create a PHP file on your server with the following code:

```
<?php 

// Set the current working directory 
$directory = "<ENTER PATH TO IMAGES FOLDER>"; 
$filecount = 0; 

$files = glob( $directory ."*" ); 

if( $files ) { 
    $filecount = count($files); 
} 

echo $filecount;

?>
```

Note: This will simply return the number of files when you visit that PHP page.

**Step 2)** Make a request to that PHP page on your server (I'd suggest to use Volley). The response of that request will contain the file count.

You can store that count in a variable and do as you wish.

Comment: Finally i try this and it work thanks now im'trying to return number on app
<?php 

// Set the current working directory 
$dir = getcwd(); 

// Initialize the counter variable to 0 
$i = 0; 

if( $handle = opendir($dir) ) { 
 
 while( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) { 
  if( !in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
   $i++; 
 } 
} 

// Display result 
echo "$i files"; 

?>